# Receiving "Subquery returns more than 1 row" in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables

1. transaction
2. members

In the transaction table all info related to transaction like id, date_of_txn, amount are fields and in members table all member related info like member id, member name, password etc. both tables are connected with `mid`. The problem is here when I want to fetch all transaction issue by member I run following query:

```
SELECT * FROM transaction
WHERE amount >=525
and amount <=2500
and txn_issued_by =(select mid from members)
```

It shows me :

```
Error Error : #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Comment: Amrita: Barmar and I had to repair quite a lot of your question to make it readable, including various misspellings of your table names, unformatted queries, and abbreviations that were not immediately clear. Please consider putting more effort into your questions in future - you may find that that people will be more minded to make an effort in answering.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE amount >=525 and amount <=2500 
and txn_issued_by IN (select mid from members)
```

Use IN instead of =

Answer (score 1):

Use a JOIN:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM transaction t
JOIN members m
ON t.txn_issued_by = m.mid
WHERE t.amount BETWEEN 525 AND 2500
```

Comment: I will do so ,Thanks a lot to your valuable suggestion